# QuickAction order different depending on position on homescreen

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, quickaction

I have a strage problem with QuickActions on iPhone. This is what I have in info.plist file:

[image: info.plist]

This it how it looks like when the app icon is on the **bottom** of the homescreen:

[image: App Icon on bottom of homescreen]

This it how it looks like when the app icon is on **the** top of the homescreen:

[image: App Icon on top of homescreen]

Why that? Why is the order of the QuickActions different depending on the position on homescreen? Is that a known issue? What can I do? Any advice?

Comment: Note also that the menu is coming from above and under in the second case. I'm wondering if the order is still the same in the same iOS version (not beta or not) according to the place of the icon (and obviously if the menu can fit at the bottom or need to be put above).

Comment: The one menu comes from above, because there's more space above. The other comes from under because there's more space under. They are on different positions. It's not the iOS system, it's the position. I'll update my question. But what can I do to fix this?

Comment: On another app that supports also QuickAction, is the result the same? If YES, you may not be able to modify it. The last item designed to be the nearest the finger. I don't have an 3DTouch device, so I never look at it, but UIApplicationShortItem is a `NSArray`, and you give at item0 the shortcut2, and at item1 the shortcut1. It seems a little illogical.

Comment: I just tried it with the PayPal app. There's the same issue.

Comment: It seems to be iOS design then.

Comment: "The last item designed to be the nearest the finger." That will be the reason. The finger is always approx. in the middle of the screen (vertically). To the user can access to every QuickAction in the same "way". You understand what I mean? So it isn't a bug, it's a feature ;)